# Jclouds dedicated timeout exceptions

Tags: java, jclouds

Is there a dedicated exception which jclouds blobstore client API throws in the case of this error:

> connect timeout, request timeout, max retries

I could not find it in the document. This information would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invokeWithTimeout` throws `com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException` which is similar to `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` but inheriting from `RuntimeException`.

[InvokeHttpMethod](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/rest/internal/InvokeHttpMethod.java) source code is in github.